# How to sandbox native node module in Electron.js application

Tags: c++, node.js, electron, node-modules, sandbox

I'm developing an Electron.js application and I extend Electron functionality with native C++ node modules which I write myself.

These modules are very platform dependent and unfortunately unstable on many machines. My app already runs in production and I have many customers which use it.

To test those native modules I try to run them in "dry" mode and I `require` them in the main Electron process. But sometimes a crash in C++ code crashes the whole application and javascript-level "dry" run doesn't help, the whole app crashes.

What are my options here? How can I safety test my native code without whole app crashing?
I was thinking about sandboxing or running new native modules in separate processes and collecting telemetry, are there any libraries or tools for Node or Electron which can simplify it?